# Issue finding out bits values from byte in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I am having an issue trying to find the bit-wise values of a Java byte type. When I try to obtain the value of a certain number of bits by using the bit-wise operator & this value is not the way I foresee it. The (very simple) code is as follows:

```
public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[]arg)
    {
        byte demo = 127;
        System.out.println("demo is: "+(demo & 00000011));
    }
}
```

In this case, I expect to obtain a 3 (since what I am expecting is 01111111 AND 00000011 = 00000011) but I obtain a 9 (00001001). If I do it with 00000111 then the result is 73 (01001001) rather than 7. Why are there two zeros that are introduced in the comparison?

I have checked the answers that were given to other questions but they are not working in my case, or are not exactly the same thing i am requesting. I am sure there must be some kind of minor thing but I am unable to find how.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 00000011 is an octal literal, value 8+1 = 9.

Comment: Thank you Patricia, it works now. I have noticed that if I add the number as a byte (for example, 3 instead of 00000011) it works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Patricia already pointed out: Java interpretes numbers starteing with leading zeros as being octal values.

If you want the number to be binary, mark it with a leading "0b":

```
System.out.println("demo is: "+(demo & 0b00000011));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! It works fine now. I have noticed that if I add the number as a byte (for example, 3 instead of 00000011) it works too.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do bitwise operators on int values (Java will do the binary conversion)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        int demo = 127;
        System.out.println(demo);
        System.out.println("demo is: " + (demo & 3));
    }
```

Reference:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

or you can convert your octal value to binary representation as:

```
00000011
to 
0b00000011
```

Which is already pointed in above answer